# Python program : Why is raw_input() blocked after signal processing? How to solve it?

Tags: python, readline, raw-input, blocked

I wrote a program that captures the system signal “ctr+z” and handle by a function. The code after handle function, is raw_input() function. I found that after the signal capture processing, the input prompt of the raw_input() function does not appear, until I press 'enter' key. what is the problem?

my code:

```
import signal
import re
import os
import readline
import shareApi

def handler(signum, frame): # ctr + z signal is 20
    if signum == 20:
        path = '/usr/local/tmpConfigFile/signal.data'
        shareApi.writeStringToFile(path, str(signum))

def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)
    prompt = "$"


    while True:
        path = '/usr/local/vSw/tmpConfigFile/signal.data'
        if os.path.exists(path):
            signum = vSwRouterShareApi.readFileToString(path)
            if signum == "20":
               prompt = "#"
            os.system("/bin/rm -f " + path)
        os.write(0,"^Z\n")
    try:    
        cmdstr = raw_input(promot)        # label
        print cmdstr
    except:
        print ""
        continue

"""
```

1. if not import readline module , the program is ok ;
2. program blocked at label, it continue woking until input 'enter' key by hand;
3. I try to use os.write() function write stdin, expect raw_input() function can read stdin , but failed.

What is the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: In general, you cannot write to stdin. In some cases—particularly when stdin goes to a user via a tty—you can, but that doesn't produce stuff that you can read back *from* stdin.

Comment: Are you really sure you still want to develop against Python 2?